# В базе данных появились символы r/n

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

после экспорта и импорта таблицы , в столбце postText появились знаки r/n ,как убрать ?

Comment: [`replace()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) ?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

это для "\n"

```
update mytable SET title = TRIM(TRAILING '\n' FROM title)
```

это для "\r"

```
update mytable SET title = TRIM(TRAILING '\r' FROM title)
```

Comment: дока http://www.mysql.ru/docs/maryan/ бурж http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html